# GlassFish Insallation\Configuration Error\Bug

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am using the latest JDK

```
# java -version
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b22)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

I have downloaded the latest Java EE SDK for Windows platform (java_ee_sdk-6u4-windows.exe), and defined a system variable `JAVA_HOME` which points to the JDK installation directory.

In the installation process of Java EE SDK, it installs GlassFish. When I try to configure the GlassFish server, the textboxes collapsed and no input can be made ([see the screenshot](http://i47.tinypic.com/34gx8k0.png)).

Is there any resolution to the problem? Is it a known bug?

Comment: Never seen this behavior. But you can still install GF separately, even by unpacking a zip file and set the configuration parameters manually.

Comment: @MattHandy, have you got any reference?

Comment: Added an answer with a reference of the GF documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange behavior, never seen it before.

You can install GF separately by unpacking a zip file and set the configuration parameters manually.

Here is a reference:

[Installing GlassFish Server From a ZIP File](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2427/ghmxb.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it is too heavy to maintaine GF this way - everything is done manually, thus you edit the configuration files and restart the GF server. This is where the configuration GUI is more comfy (with the server auto-restart). Besides, I still have to install Java EE SDK (which is bundled with GF). Correct?